# Why does CDC's RT-PCR protocol for Covid-19 use the N gene, but the Charite one the E gene and RdRp?

Tags: covid-19, test, sars-cov-2, center-disease-control, pcr

The Charite protocol mentioned among other things [that](https://www.eurosurveillance.org/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES.2020.25.3.2000045)

> Of note, the N gene assay also performed well but was not subjected to intensive further validation because it was slightly less sensitive.

On the other hand, the [CDC protocol](https://www.fda.gov/media/134922/download) (updated in March) uses the N gene (and not the other two used by Charite's, i.e. the E gene and RdRp). So, did the CDC find the opposite? Or were other factors the CDC considered (more important)? The long CDC document doesn't seem to answer this...

Comment: Great question! And solid answer as well.

Comment: Please do remind me when one is able to set a bounty if I forget (it should be 48h after the question was posted, no?). This answer deserves some recognition!

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is the explanation I found in a (different) CDC [paper](https://wwwnc.cdc.gov/eid/article/26/8/20-1246_article):

> First, we based assay designs on previous diagnostic assays that had been developed for detection of MERS-CoV (12) and SARS-CoV (10) and targeted the N gene. **Because of the relative abundance of N gene subgenomic mRNA produced during virus replication (13), rRT-PCR assays targeting the N gene of coronaviruses could theoretically achieve enhanced diagnostic sensitivity.** One study also showed that the N gene–based rRT-PCR assay was more sensitive than the open reading frame (ORF) 1 assay for detection of SARS-CoV-2 in clinical specimens ([14](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7108203/)). Second, we designed rRT-PCR assays on the basis of limited genetic information available soon after the emergence of SARS-CoV-2, when it was announced that a novel coronavirus of zoonotic origin was described as being similar to bat-SARS–like CoVs and only 1 SARS-CoV-2 sequence was publicly available. The N3 assay was intentionally designed to universally detect SARS-CoV-2 and other SARS-like sarbecoviruses to ensure detection of SARS-CoV-2 as this virus evolves over time and to improve early identification of future emerging novel coronaviruses from this high-risk subgenus. After completion of this study, the sequence of a new bat-SARS–like CoV, RaTG13 (EPI_SL_402131), was released on GISAID. Detected in 2013 from China, this virus appears to be the nearest bat precursor of SARS-CoV-2 (15), having 96% genome and 97% N gene sequence identity with SARS-CoV-2. All 3 assays are predicted to detect the RaTG13 strain.

So it seems to have been combination of factors of wanting a "universal platform" that could target related viruses as well as the supposed abundance of the N gene making this (CDC) approach more sensitive. However there's no concrete data on comparing it with an alternative approach in this paper. The study "14" ([Chu, Pan, Poon et al.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7108203/)) they cite in support is from China/HK. (Also of note regarding the Charite protocol in relation to this, the E gene isn't located in ORF 1, although the RdRp is.)

From a more recent comparison paper [(Meijer et al.)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1386653220301542) of commercial kits--comparison paper which shares authors with the original Charite protocol paper--, tests that use the E gene have some cross-reactivity with SARS-CoV-1, but this is also "by design" in order to target multiple viruses on their platform

> In this set-up, the E-gene primer/probe set is specific for bat(-related) betacoronaviruses, and therefore detects both SARS-CoV-1 and -2. In addition, whereas the RdRp-gene primers are also specific for bat(-related) betacoronaviruses, two probes are used: one specific for bat(-related) betacoronaviruses and another specific for SARS-CoV-2.

Interestingly perhaps, none of the tests in this comparison (Meijer et al.) were pure N gene tests, like the CDC one. (There were some that combined an N gene test with another, e.g. one from Spain [ORF1ab, N] and one from Korea [RdRp, N, E]; the RdRp is located in ORF1ab.) Meijer et al.'s selection of kits comes from the broader [FIND project](http://www.finddx.org/covid-19/sarscov2-eval-molecular/), which also doesn't shortlist any pure N tests.